# Error: SEVERE:Cannot create agent

Tags: java, agents-jade

I can't run agent BookBuyerAgent.

Path to project is **D:\studia\magisterka\sem10\jade\JADE-all-4.1.1(1)\JADE-all-4.1\jade\src\examples\bookTrading\src**.
At first I do **javac BookBuyerAgent.java** and this OK. Second I do **java jade.Boot agent1:examples\bookTrading\src\BookBuyerAgent**  and I get error:

```
D:\studia\magisterka\sem10\jade\JADE-all-4.1.1(1)\JADE-all-4.1\jade\src\examples
\bookTrading\src>java jade.Boot tu:examples\bookTrading\src\BookSellerGui
sie 27, 2012 8:13:27 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
This is JADE snapshot - revision $WCREV$ of $WCDATE$
downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.messaging.MessagingService clearCachedSlice
INFO: Clearing cache
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.mtp.http.HTTPServer <init>
INFO: HTTP-MTP Using XML parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParse
rImpl$JAXPSAXParser
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.messaging.MessagingService boot
INFO: MTP addresses:
http://10.1.242.245:7778/acc
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents
SEVERE: Cannot create agent tu: Class examples\bookTrading\src\BookSellerGui for
agent ( agent-identifier :name tu@mariusz:1099/JADE ) not found [nested java.la
ng.ClassNotFoundException: examples\bookTrading\src\BookSellerGui]
sie 27, 2012 8:13:28 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Main-Container@mariusz is ready.
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

bookTrading\src folder is probably a source folder (containing .java files). You should set your classpath accordingly to the bookTrading\bin folder and give class name to Jade command line.

Comment: Yes, bookTrading\src is folder containing .java files. So to CLASSPATH I should add path to bookTrading\bin and then try compile .java files?